# Transition não funciona na troca de classes com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, transição

Tenho um menu dropdown feito por mim que atua com troca de classes bem simples(`block` ou `none`).

O script funciona e atualiza a classes da maneira correta, mas aparentemente ele ignora a propriedade `transition` da classe e não faz o efeito de fade.

Tentei colocar setTimeout mas não resolveu.
Tentei colocar a transition em uma classe à parte e chamar as duas e não deu.

Código > http://jsfiddle.net/tsuhdm2c/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é possivel fazer animação da propriedade `display` vais ter de usar `opacity`.

Fiz mais uns ajustes ao código e deixo uma sugestão simplificada. Nota que mudei no JavaScript bastante pois a API `classList` tem o método `.toggle()` e assim não precisas de verificar se a classe lá está

Exemplo:

```js
var botao_menu = document.querySelector('.header .btn');
var menu = document.getElementById('idmenu');

function switchbtn(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    menu.classList.toggle('aberto');
}

botao_menu.addEventListener('click', switchbtn, false);
```

```css
.header {
    margin:0 auto;
    height:90px;
    width:200px;
    text-align:center;
}
.header .btn {
    background-color:#000;
    display: inline-block;
    width:inherit;
    color:#fff;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.header .menu {
    list-style:none;
    background-color:#488ac6;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1.2s;
}
/* estilos de animação */
 .aberto {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"> <a class="btn">Botao abre/fecha Menu</a>

    <ul class="menu" id="idmenu">
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: você como sempre me salvando. Obrigado man

Comment: @ropbla9 :) fico sempre contente de ajudar

Comment: o '.fechado' era totalmente desnecessário. Coloquei porque tava desesperando a tentar tudo, hahaha.

Comment: vc poderia entrar http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67022/sergio-ropbla9. Tentei te chamar la mas parece que n ta indo